# export 'Button' (imported as 'Button') was not found in './Button' in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

hope you all doing well, i am very new in react and i was following the guide, but got stuck with this  strange problem while I import { Button} from './Button'. Ill provide the full code :

```
import React from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import  { Button }  from './Button';
import './HeroSection.css';


function HeroSection() {
return (
<div className='hero-container'>

    <div className="hero-btns">
        <Button 
        className='btns' 
        buttonStyle='btn--outline' 
        buttonSize='btn--large'>Get Started</Button>
        <Button 
        className='btns' 
        buttonStyle='btn--primary' 
        buttonSize='btn--large'>Checkout Events
         <i className='far fa-play-circle' /></Button>
    </div>
</div>
     )
     }

export default HeroSection
```

Here is a Button.js code also:

```
  import React from 'react';
  import './Button.css';
  import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

  const STYLES= ['btn--primary', 'btn--outline'];
  const SIZES= ['btn--medium', 'btn--large'];
  export const Buttom =({children, type, onClick, buttonStyle, 
  buttonSize}) => {const checkButtonStyle= 
  STYLES.includes(buttonStyle) ? buttonStyle : STYLES[0]
  const checkButtonSize = SIZES.includes(buttonSize) ? buttonSize : 
  SIZES[0]

return(
    <Link to='/Login' className='btn-mobile'>
        <button
        className={`btn ${checkButtonStyle} ${checkButtonSize}`}
        onClick={onClick}
        type={type}
        >
            {children}
        </button>
        
        </Link>
)
  };
```

---

Already Tried to put Button without {}, and tired to export default Button but it didn't fixed it at all :(

Comment: can you show your button component as well? how it's exported

Comment: added button code to the question

Comment: Hey @Matvey. Can you try fixing the typo in Button Component. `export const Buttom`. It says Buttom not button

Comment: @MCNaveen when i fix this typo error, it shows another error that button is not defined

Comment: you have a typo at line 7. `Buttom` <==========

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the above is the exact `Button.js` file you've used

then it's just a typo, change `Buttom` to `Button` at line 7, and you're good to go

---

Apart from that, you can simply export the `Button` as default

By adding this line

```js
export default Button;
```

then you'll have to import it like

```
import Button from './Button';
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a sample code for you with Button Example.

Here is the App.js file

```
import "./styles.css";
import Button from "./Button";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Button btnText="I'm a Button" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the Button Component.

```
function Button({ btnText }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button>{btnText}</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Button;
```

here is the [codesanbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-pond-kmb0f5?file=/src/Button.js:0-127)

Here is how it looks.

[image]